# how to make Generic method for rest call in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

how to make Generic method for rest call in angularjs ?

i have tried for single request, it's working fine

```
UIAppRoute.controller('test', ['$scope', 'checkStatus', function($scope, checkStatus) {
    $scope.data = {};
    checkStatus.query(function(response) {
      $scope.data.resp = response;
    });
}])



UIAppResource.factory('checkStatus', function($resource){
    return $resource(baseURL + 'status', {}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}})
})
```

I want to make this as generic for all the request

Please share any sample,.. thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/08/16/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service.aspx

Comment: Thanks Patxy, but i'm not using $http, so please share some other links

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something like this :

```
.factory('factoryResource', ['$resource', 'CONF',
    function($resource, CONF) {
        return {
            get: function(endPoint, method) {
                var resource = $resource(CONF.baseUrl + endPoint, {}, {
                    get: {
                        method: method || 'GET'
                    }
                });

                return resource.get().$promise;
            }
        };
    }
])
```

called by :

```
factoryResource.get(CONF.testEndPoint, "POST"); // make a POST and return a promise and a data object
factoryResource.get(CONF.testEndPoint, "GET"); // make a GETand return a promise and a data object
factoryResource.get(CONF.testEndPoint); // make a GETand return a promise and a data object
```

with a config file having :

```
angular.module('app.constant', [])

.constant('CONF', {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8787',
    testEndPoint: '/api/test'
});
```

Comment: how to pass the parameters and how to change **GET** method to **POST**

Comment: don't you know how to pass parameters to a function ? See my `get: function(endPoint) {` line ? add as much parameter as you want and refactor the code...

Comment: sorry Bixi, i'm new for angularjs.. i'm not getting clear idea. pls explain

Comment: It's not about angular, it's plain logic.. If you want to choose between POST or GET, jsut add a new parameter `method` (or add a "post" method) ... see my edit. Can't help you more if you don't understand that. Mark as resolved if it's OK.